# Substituting Date values with CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a set of records, which contains a Date1 column and a Date2 column. If a record has the Date1 value less than a particular date, then that value will be substituted with the value in the Date2 column for that record.
The Date columns have type date. I'm trying to use a CASE statement but I get the new value for ALL records for some reason.

Comment: You want a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: It would help to show your attempt at a case expression so we can help explain what you are doing wrong. It may be as simple as specifying your fixed date incorrectly, e.g. by relying on implicit conversion; but showing sample data (with full dates) might be useful too.

Comment: I think my issue lies in the date comparison part. What's the correct way to compare the date? My database is Oracle.

Comment: @SoumyadeepPaul -the answer from Ronnis shows how to compare dates. Again, if you edit your question to show what you've tried we can help you figure out why it isn't working as you expect. Please include sample data and expected results; and say whether either date column can be null, and what should happen if they are.

Answer (score 0):

What about nulls?

```
select case when date1 < date '2016-01-01' then date2 else date1 end as your_date
  from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
CASE
    WHEN Date1 < @DateVariable
        THEN Date2
    ELSE Date1
END DateResult
```

Comment: Putting `@` before a variable is not valid Oracle syntax. Use `:` for a bind variable or `&` for a substitution variable or, if it is a constant value, just use an ANSI date literal.

Comment: It was just a placeholder to show how it would look

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have that particular date in a variable such as :

```
DELCARE particularDate DATE
SET particularDate = '6/10/2016'
```

And you have your table such as :

```
CREATE TABLE Tab(ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(100), Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE)
INSERT INTO Tab VALUES(1, 'A', '10/10/2016', '11/10/2016')
INSERT INTO Tab VALUES(2, 'B', '9/10/2016', '12/16/2016')
INSERT INTO Tab VALUES(3, 'C', '1/10/2016', '11/10/2016')
INSERT INTO Tab VALUES(4, 'D', '2/10/2016', '4/10/2016')
INSERT INTO Tab VALUES(5, 'E', '4/10/2016', '2/10/2016')
```

The table will look like this :

```
ID  Name      Date1       Date2
1    A      2016-10-10  2016-11-10
2    B      2016-09-10  2016-12-16
3    C      2016-01-10  2016-11-10
4    D      2016-02-10  2016-04-10
5    E      2016-04-10  2016-02-10
```

Then you can use the following query :

```
SELECT      t.ID,
            t.Name,
            CASE
                WHEN (t.Date1 < particularDate)
                THEN t.Date2
                ELSE t.Date1
            END AS GreaterDate
FROM        Tab t
```

This would give you the following result :

```
ID  Name    GreaterDate
1    A      2016-10-10
2    B      2016-09-10
3    C      2016-11-10
4    D      2016-04-10
5    E      2016-02-10
```

**It would be useful if you specify what should occur in case `Date1` and that particular date are equal.** You can then explicitly define the result of this condition. You can do something like this :

```
SELECT      t.ID,
            t.Name,
            CASE
                WHEN (t.Date1 < particularDate) THEN t.Date2
                WHEN (t.Date1 > particularDate) THEN t.Date1
                ELSE t.Date1          --when date1 and particularDate are equal
            END AS GreaterDate
FROM        Tab t
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Putting @'s before the variable names won't work in Oracle.

Comment: @Boneist Yup, you're right!! My bad, I wrote it on SQL Server Management Studio where that's needed.Should've removed it before pasting here. Thanks for pointing it out.Have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: `'10/10/2016'` is a string literal and not a date literal - Oracle will implicitly try to convert this to a date using the NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter however, this is a client setting and is neither guaranteed to be static nor consistent between users. If you want to use literals then use ANSI date literals `DATE '2016-10-10'`

Answer (score 0):

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

SELECT 
   CASE WHEN DATE1 < TO_DATE('1900/01/02 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') THEN DATE2 ELSE DATE1 END AS DATE_OF_INTEREST 
   FROM TABLE;

Comment: How is that different to what Ronnis said hours ago - other than using `to_date()` instead of a date literal?